# How to grep for a specific text after executing a command in terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, grep, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm executing

```
eb deploy my_env,
```

After which quite a bit of text is shown in command line, and I would like to `grep` for `"update completed successfully"` *Upon Completion* of the above command, and if not found return an exit status of 1.

I was wondering how this is possible.

(If you're interested in why, I've found that eb deployments despite a deploy failure return an exit status of 0)

Comment: `eb deploy my_env | grep "update completed successfully"`?

Comment: Thanks @MadPhysicist, is there a limit to number of pipes? The actually command is a bit more involved:

eb deploy my_env | sed blah blah blah , can i do:

eb deploy my_env | sed blah blah blah | grep "update completed successfully" ?

Comment: @HosseinK. Sure. That's exactly how you use pipes. I'll update my answer.

Comment: More updates. Enjoy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a textbook case of what pipes are used for:

```
eb deploy my_env | grep "update completed successfully"
```

If you want to suppress the output of [`grep`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/grep1.html), use the `-q` flag. The result will act just as if `eb deploy` had an error code that actually matched your needs:

```
eb deploy my_env | grep -q "update completed successfully"
```

As you mention in your comments, `eb deploy my_env` can actually be any other pipeline of commands that contains `"update completed successfully"` somewhere in the final output. The return value for the entire pipeline will be the return value of `grep`, being the last command.

This type of piping is actually a fundamental principle of UNIX design. UNIX commands are ideally small blocks that perform one single function and do it well. The idea is that it is much easier to pipe together some number of robust modules than to write a single very complex program that does everything.

**Interesting Update**

You can actually see the raw output from `eb deploy` and still use `grep` to determine the return code. The simplest way (which better illustrates chained pipes) is to use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), which is available in `bash`, `ksh` and `zsh`:

```
eb deploy my_env | tee >(cat) | grep -q "update completed successfully"
```

[`tee`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/tee1.html) will duplicate the output to a file and `stdout`. `stdout` will be piped to `grep` as before. Instead of specifying a file, we use a sub-process `>(cat)`, which will just print the output to the command line.

For other, more portable methods, refer to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40277/79307) on Unix/Linux stack exchange for more info.

Comment: `grep -q` will stop on the first match and may not allow the command to run to completion

Comment: @thatotherguy. OP just wants to convert the return code, so that's perfectly fine.

Comment: OP specifies "*Upon Completion* of the above command", emphasis theirs

Comment: @thatotherguy. From a pedantic point of view you are right. I just can't imagine the line `"update completed successfully"` being printed on anything by a successful *completion* of the command.

Comment: Dunno.. I could imagine a tool like apt or yum going "Updating list of packages.. Update completed successfully.. Installing requested packages.."

Comment: @thatotherguy Sure, but given OP's use case, you'd be grepping for the specific thing that it prints at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

Grep returns an exit code. To use only the exit code without outputting the match, use the following:

```
if <command> | grep -q "<text>"; then ...
```

*`-q` is for quiet mode.*

Answer (score -1):

Pipe the output to a file.  Then grep that output.

```
eb deploy my_env > deploy_results.txt
grep 'update completed successfully' deploy_results.txt
```

Comment: The OP is clearly a beginner.  I was more concerned with introducing the idea of saving to a file and grepping than any sense of efficiency.

Comment: Why are you introducing saving to a file?